# Hibernate error "unable to locate persister"

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, jpa

I am trying to execute some Java with the Maven exec plugin, and am getting an error `Caused by: org.hibernate.UnknownEntityTypeException: Unable to locate persister: my.biz.CoolEntity`. I tried a number of failed solutions, before ultimately finding a hacky fix. Based on the hacky fix, I believe the issue to be a runtime classpath error.

I am looking for an answer that will tell me how to address the problem without resorting to copying the needed files into place, as I do in the hacky fix.

**Background**

I have a Maven project "Project A" which has dependencies upon Hibernate 5.0.1.Final as well as another project "Project B". Project B contains my JPA entity classes, including `my.biz.CoolEntity`.

Normally, I build everything into a shaded JAR and run/deploy that, without any issues.

**Hibernate issue**

Recently, I began using Maven's `exec:java` goal, but am running into what on the surface is a Hibernate issue. when I run `mvn exec:java -DmainClass=my.biz.CoolEntity`, I get this error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.UnknownEntityTypeException: Unable to locate persister: my.biz.CoolEntity
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.locateEntityPersister(SessionFactoryImpl.java:792) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.1.Fi
nal.jar:5.0.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.locateEntityPersister(SessionImpl.java:2641) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.1.Final.jar:5.0.1
.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.access$2500(SessionImpl.java:164) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.1.Final.jar:5.0.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.<init>(SessionImpl.java:2579) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.1.Final
.jar:5.0.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.<init>(SessionImpl.java:2566) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.1.Final
.jar:5.0.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.byId(SessionImpl.java:1044) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.1.Final.jar:5.0.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:955) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.1.Final.jar:5.0.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.find(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1075) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.
0.1.Final.jar:5.0.1.Final]
```

**Failed attempts**

I tried making use of the exec plugin's [`<additionalClasspathElements>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19199709/614660) and [`<includePluginDependencies>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11711997/614660). The first solution didn't result in any different, and the second resulted in a compile-time error.

**Hacky fix**

What ended up working for me was copying the compiled classes from Project B into Project A.

Answer (score 4):

Try changing the imports from "javax" to "jakarta". I had the same issue and mine worked when I made the change.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32199617)

Answer (score 1):

When the entities are residing in a different jar, you have to include it in persistence.xml.  `<jar-file>entities-packaged.jar</jar-file>`.  Different options are explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4433341/what-is-the-right-path-to-refer-a-jar-file-in-jpa-persistence-xml-in-a-web-app)

Answer (score 0):

When we use Hibernate 5 jars, then we get

> org.hibernate.UnknownEntityTypeException: Unable to locate persister".

I just changed the hibernate jar versions from 5 to 4 and then everything was fine.
Hibernate 5 does not locate the entity classes even after mapping.

Answer (score 0):

I too got the same exception and it was due to missing the entity annotation `@Entity` for the class. Please check if the `@Entity` annotation is available in your class

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was using Java 17 and a newer version of hibernate-core and trying to `import javax.persistence.*`. I started with [this example](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/hibernate-example-using-jpa-and-mysql/) and tried to upgrade hibernate-core to a newer version (6.2.7.Final) and got the error `Unable to locate persister`.

Original pom.xml:

```xml
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.2.7.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.214</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Original imports:

```java
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
```

The `hibernate-core` dependency pulls in persistence implicitly so explicitly pulling it in like that (and an older version) was my mistake. I just needed to change my pom dependencies to this:

```xml
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.2.7.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.214</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

And change my imports to this:

```java
import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;
```

... and it all worked fine after that.